# What is the significance of the pink phone in "The Great Game"?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, character, sherlock

I would like to know why does Moriarty go through so much trouble to make a replica of the phone from "A Study in Pink" in the *Sherlock* episode "The Great Game"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to show him that he's been following him for a while, and knows a lot of details about his life.

Answer (score 0):

It's to show the connection between the crimes that only Sherlock would realize, so that none of the people at the police station would try to keep Sherlock out of it. Also, it shows that even though the criminal knows so much about Sherlock, he did not use the actual phone because he needed to see how good Sherlock was